# My MacBook Pro 2018 (Intel) reaches 100 degrees Celsius very often

Tags: macbook-pro, temperature, intel

I am curious if this is ok. It reaches this temperature very often when some intensive tasks are running. Sometimes it reaches this temperature when application is starting. Fan starts to spin up to 100% slowly.

Recently my Mac was serviced and they told me that they had replaced thermal paste under the processor.

I don’t know how was the temperatures before the service visit.

Update:
I have used Endurance: CPU Stress Test to stress cpu and observe temperatures when fans are running 100%. These are my results. Can someone do the same test?
[image]

Comment: Another case of CPU-monitoring apps giving users perfectly normal data to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Intel CPUs can run at 100°C under normal load. That's why Apple moved to their own CPUs, which don't turn half the battery to heat.

[My Macbook reached 100 degrees Celsius while compiling a software package, is this normal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65273/my-macbook-reached-100-degrees-celsius-while-compiling-a-software-package-is-th)

[Ridiculously high CPU temperature and fan speeds on MacBook Pro Retina, late 2013](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115141/ridiculously-high-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speeds-on-macbook-pro-retina-late-201?rq=1)

If you're getting temps of 86°C when the fans are running full tilt, then the fans are doing a very good job.